# Pasting a file from a location to a folder within a previously define folder name

Tags: powershell, variables, copy-item

Very new to Powershell and i'm learning from a work colleague.

I have a script which will give me a cycle date and name 6 folders with the cycle date in the folder name.

Within each 6 folders i have created 3 folders. Data, Delivery, Support

My script below creates me the folders.

```
#Folder Directories
$AIRAC_Customer1 = "AIRAC" + $AIRAC_Month +"Ford"
$AIRAC_Customer2 = "AIRAC" + $AIRAC_Month +"VW"
$AIRAC_Customer3 = "AIRAC" + $AIRAC_Month +"AUDI"
$AIRAC_Customer4 = "AIRAC" + $AIRAC_Month +"Peugeot"
$AIRAC_Customer5 = "AIRAC" + $AIRAC_Month +"KIA"
$AIRAC_Customer6 = "AIRAC" + $AIRAC_Month +"BMW"

#Customer Array
$Customer_Array = $AIRAC_Customer1, $AIRAC_Customer2, $AIRAC_Customer3, $AIRAC_Customer4, $AIRAC_Customer5, $AIRAC_Customer6


# produce next AIRAC Cycle date
$Year = Get-Date -format yy
$DofY = (Get-Date).DayOfYear
$Lunar_Month = [math]::ceiling( $DofY/28)
if ($Lunar_Month -lt 10) {$Lunar_Month = "0"+$Lunar_Month+1}
if ($Lunar_Month -ge 13) {$Lunar_Month = "13"}
if ($DofY -gt 340) {
    $Year = [int]$Year+1 
    $Lunar_Month = "01"
}
$AIRAC_Month = [String]$Year + [String]$Lunar_Month

foreach ($element in $Customer_Array) 

{
    $Folder = $element
    $Folder2 = $Folder + "\Data"
    $Folder3 = $Folder + "\Delivery"
    $Folder4 = $Folder + "\Support (DO NOT DELETE THIS FOLDER OR ITS CONTENTS)"

    mkdir $Folder 
    mkdir $Folder2
    mkdir $Folder3
    mkdir $Folder4
    Write-Output $Folder
}
```

I'm trying to test it by writing something along the lines of the following so that i am able to copy files with a specific name (*TN.pdf) from a location and paste it into each of the 'Data' folders. But putting the parameter in the test path to see if i can find it isnt working for me...

```
Test-Path C:\Users\J.B\[ref]$AIRAC_Customer4\Data
```

I hope I've explained this well enough.

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Please note:  1. You are initializing `$AIRAC_Month` after you used them 2. You are just creating the foldername, no full path. I'd expect something like `C:\temp\AIRAC\$AIRAC_Month\Ford`. Also, you don't need to reference `[ref]` the variable here in `test-path`. Is the file copied, but your check just fails?

Comment: i always first create a variable for the folder/file to test like `$testPath = 'C:\Users\J.B\{0}\Data' -f $AIRAC_Customer4`. this replaces `{0}` with the first parameter after `-f` (and could be countless by comma separation). once that is done try `Test-Path $testPath`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly: So do you mean 1) i presume, i'm creating the AIRAC date after i've used them in the lines above? 2) I'm not really following sorry... 
yeah i've got the test path working. I may not have had the file in there before.

Comment: 1) yes 2) by "AIRAC" + $AIRAC_Month +"Ford"`` you are not creating a full path but only a foldername. I would expect a full path like `C:\temp\airac...` - and finally: So you got `test-path`working, which means your code is working now?

Comment: Thanks for your time and comments. I'll have a look into that and see if i can use that method.